# Convert array in string form to actual Array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string in this format

```
"[abc, def, igh]"
```

and want to convert it to an actual Array in JS

I tried parsing the sring with JSON.parse but it s giving unexpected token error.

Comment: Fix whatever's serving you that odd string so that it gives you JSON instead.

Comment: The reason of token error is invalid JSON string. First convert it into a valid JSON then parse.

Comment: One line: `JSON.parse('[abc, def, igh]'.replace(/(\w+)/g,'"$1"'));`

Comment: @adiga It runs perfectly in Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit), so ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas sorry, my bad. I mistook the closing brackets of `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas: Also one line: `'[abc, def, igh]'.match(/\w+/g) || []`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) like this:

```js
let str = "[abc, def, igh]",
    array = str.slice(1, -1).split(/,\s?/);
    
console.log(array)
```

This is just a workaround. You should fix your string to be a valid JSON if you can.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```js
let myString = "[abc, def, igh]"

//myString = myString.replace('[','')
//myString = myString.replace(']','')

myString = myString.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'') // regex alternative to above 2 lines

// splits string using comma and build an array
myArray = myString.split(',')

// loop through array and log
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(myArray[i].trim()); // trim to remove unwanted spaces
}
```